# Why do we need to pass View objects to some methods?

Tags: android, android-view

I am new to android and have very few experience in Java. I don't understand why some methods require View objects.

This is a method which is called when a button is clicked on an activity.

```
public void eatCookie(View view) { //Example code inside

    ImageView previous = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.android_cookie_image_view);
    previous.setImageResource(R.drawable.after);
    TextView previousText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text_view);
    previousText.setText("I'm so full!");
    }
```

In this code, there is no line which uses the view object. This code is from a udacity tutorial. Why could they have not formed the "eatCookie" method like this:

```
public void eatCookie() {.....}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right explanation but check [this](http://terokarvinen.com/2011/simple-button-for-android-xml-onclick-public-method). You may need to check that layout file you might found an onClick property for a view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do you need to pass an object of type View to this method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618368/why-do-you-need-to-pass-an-object-of-type-view-to-this-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the object view is indeed useless.

But in other cases like in a fragment you would do somethnig like this to get the view from the inflated layout view :

```
public void eatCookie(View view) { //Example code inside
    ImageView previous = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.android_cookie_image_view);
    previous.setImageResource(R.drawable.after);
    TextView previousText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.status_text_view);
    previousText.setText("I'm so full!");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This question is answered here :
[Why do you need to pass an object of type View to this method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618368/why-do-you-need-to-pass-an-object-of-type-view-to-this-method)
Please check it carefully.

Good Luck

Comment: The accepted answer in the question you linked starts with "You might have several buttons in your layout..." This is not a definite answer and explores possible use cases. This question contains code from Udacity, where it couldn't have been concluded for sure that the answer from the linked question was applicable to this case as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have taken a few Udacity courses - I expect they would later utilize this View object. If it isn't - in a real world scenario, this would be an unexpected implementation. The parameter's in a method are expected to be used by that method. I wouldn't sweat it if I were you - keep progressing!

Answer (score 0):

Every item in a user interface is a subclass of the Android View class (to be precise android.view.View). The Android SDK provides a set of pre-built views that can be used to construct a user interface. Typical examples include standard items such as the Button, CheckBox, ProgressBar and TextView classes. Such views are also referred to as widgets.

A view can also be comprised of multiple other views (otherwise known as a composite view). Such views are subclassed from the Android ViewGroup class (android.view.ViewGroup) which is itself a subclass of View. An example of such a view is the RadioGroup,